# Apache redirecting to unsecure port

Tags: tls, apache

I have setup a test website in order to play around setting up SSL.  The website is setup on a Windows host with Apache 2.2.20 with OpenSSL 0.9.8r, MySQL 5.5.37, PHP 5.3.28.  The URL to the home page of the website is http://example.com/index.php.  Once you get to the index.php page, you are instantly redirected to http://example.com/login.php.

I setup SSL with a self-signed cert.  When I navigated to index.php on https, I get the error stating the certificate does not match the server.  I click on "Continue to this website (not recommended)."  I receive the message "You are about to view pages over a secure connection."  I select ok, and I immediately receive the message "You are about to leave a secure Internet connection."  I select yes I want to continue.  IE errors out and states "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage."

If I navigate directly to login.php on https, it works as expected.

My question is...  What would be causing Apache to start loading secure and then switching to unsecure?

Comment: You are redirecting without taking the scheme into account, probably.

Comment: What do you redirect to? Do you include the schema?
Are you listening on both 80 and 443?

Answer (score 1):

It is very likely that you're simply doing something like this:

```
<?php

if ( ! $is_logged_in) {
    header('Location: http://example.com/login.php');
    exit;
}
```

Just change your redirect url to `https`, and everything should work as intended.

Comment: In this case it is best to leave the protocol completely. Just redirect to `/login.php` and the browser will handle http/https.

Comment: I think it's required (according to specifications) to include the full url in redirect headers. A vast majority of browsers will handle relative URLs correctly, but it might cause problems in some cases. Also, having the https protocol present ensures that http:/example.com will always redirect to the secure login page.

Comment: Well, thats a difference. Anyways, I'd use a constant `WEBROOT` instead of hardcoding the https or the domain, just best-practice.

Comment: @marstato — yes, certainly. Or probably something like an appliction-specific get_full_url('login') helper.